# Hook Right Mouse + Paste Event Windows C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Currently I make an application on Windows.

I want to listen for an event when the user right-clicks and selects Paste in other applications.

I use [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookex), but it just captures the right mouse click.

Comment: What kind of hook are you using? Probably only `WH_MOUSE/_LL`. A `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook can catch `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_PASTE` messages being sent to a window.

Comment: I try WH_CALLWNDPROC, It work perfectly for notepad, but Chrome not notify WM_PASTE message when i paste

Comment: note that I also mentioned `WM_COMMAND`. That is used when menu items are invoked. Use a tool like Spy++ to monitor the messages that Chrome generates when its Paste menu item is invoked. Like Jeanine said, a `WM_PASTE` message is not always generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Remy Lebeau. If you want to capture paste, you could create a global `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook (SetWindowsHookEx), and captured all WM_PASTE messages.

However [wm_paste message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-paste) is only sent to an edit control or combo box.

If you want to capture other paste messages (like in word, notepad and etc.).I suggest you could try to [add a window to the Clipboard Viewer Chain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard#adding-a-window-to-the-clipboard-viewer-chain).Clipboard viewer windows receive a WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD message whenever the content of the clipboard changes.

Comment: For clipboard viewer chain, I received WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD when user copy, but not when user paste. I need capture paste action

Comment: @TienThanh there is no clipboard notification when a paste happens. The closest thing is if the copying code uses [delayed-rendering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard-operations#delayed-rendering) to put data on the clipboard on-demand, then a paste will trigger a `WM_RENDERFORMAT` message. But that is rare.

Comment: WM_RENDERFORMAT work as I expected, thank you so much